# Call function when each list item is at 50vh

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a rather large list (150 items) that can be scrolled. When a list item is at the middle of the page (50vh) i want it to call a function.

What is the best way to go about this, I can do it own scroll but then it would be checking 150 items on every pixel scrolled which is too heavy on the processor. The function would then change data in a separate div to relate to the current list item scrolling.

Is there a better way of doing it? I have seen gsap, but wasn't sure of a way to call a function when a list item is at 50vh

Comment: Is each item in that list the same height? You could just attach a single scroll event listener to the parent if so, and calculate from the scroll position which item is in the middle.

Comment: They are actually different sizes as the fonts get bigger dependant on the size.

Comment: Then maybe you could do a binary search starting in the middle of the list on scroll of the parent, checking the position of each item.  You could also debounce the search so it only runs when the scrolling stops.